# How to exit from a running block command container?

Tags: docker, containers

I use below content Dockerfile builded a alphine-test image:

```
FROM rarenicks/alphine 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/ /app 
RUN echo 321 >> test.txt   
CMD tail -f test.txt
```

you see the CDM `tail -f test.txt` is a block command.

when I run the image as a container:

```
[root@att dockerfiles]# docker run alphine-test:v1.0 
WARNING: IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work.
321
^C
quit
^C
^Z
^P
^Z^X^C^
```

now I cannot exit from the container now.

Comment: Open another terminal window and `docker stop` the container.  (And consider making your `CMD` something that actually runs the application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the container in "interactive mode":

```
docker run --interactive --tty alphine-test:v1.0
```